# Find a custom tag content in jQuery

Tags: jquery, find

Form a variable like this:

```
var pageDetails = '<html><head>...';
```

How can I the custom tag content ?

```
<span itemprop="streetAddress">71 Rue De La Commune Ouest</span>
```

I'm using actually this code:

```
$(pageDetails).find(attr("streetAddress")).text()
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(pageDetails).find('[itemprop="streetAddress"]').text()
```

This is the attribute matching syntax of jQuery selectors.

The double-quotes are not required unless the search string contains special characters (space - etc), but generally a good thing to always have in this type of search.

e.g. you could just have

```
$(pageDetails).find('[itemprop=streetAddress]').text()
```

You also have the slightly shorter version, that uses `$` with a `context` (instead of find, comes in handy):

```
$('[itemprop=streetAddress]', pageDetails).text()
```

Comment: Grr so simple and clever. Thanks TrueBlueAussie.